# The seven piece silver chain

Tags: logical-deduction

You have to stay for 7 days in a hotel outside your city. But you forgot to bring your credit card and are out of cash.

You have a silver chain with 7 links. The rule in this hotel is that residents should pay their rent every morning. The manager of the hotel is well aware of your situation and says that you can pay one link of your silver necklace every morning instead of money.

But he wants the chain in good condition. So he suggests a solution for your every morning payment with only ONE link cut in the chain.

What is his solution?

source: [fekraneh.ir](http://www.fekraneh.ir/tab-178/index.aspx)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Answer:

> Cut the 3rd link.
> 1. On day 1 you give him the cut link
> 2. On day 2 you give him 1-2, he returns the cut link
> 3. On day 3 you give the cut link, along with the 1-2 he has.
> 4. On day 4 you swap your 4-5-6-7 for the 1-2 and 3
> 5. On day 5 you give the cut link (so manager has 4-5-6-7 and the cut link 3)
> 6. On day 6 you swap 1-2 for cut link 3 (so manager has 1-2 and 4-5-6-7)
> 7. On day 7 you give the remaining cut link 3.